# Can I run PhantomJS without downloading the binary manually?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, phantomjs

I am trying to make a program run on both Windows and Linux without having to download the binaries manually all the time. I wonder if it is possible to port my tester by removing the filepath somehow and adding that through maven?

```
    DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    File path = new File("C:\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe"); 
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", path.getAbsolutePath());        
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager), it is a Maven dependency that automatically downloads the necessary binaries.